# IEEE class does not print long equations more than one page or one column

Tags: equations, eqnarray, sseq

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq6}
\begin{array}{l}
MI\left( {{E_i},{E^t},E_k^n,E_l^m} \right) =
\\p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 0} \right)\\
\\
 \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 0} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 0} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 0} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 0} \right)}}} \right)\\
 \\
 + p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 1} \right)\\
 \\
 \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 0} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 0} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 1} \right)}}} \right)\\
 \\
 + p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 1,E_l^m = 0} \right)\\
 \\
 \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 1,E_l^m = 0} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 0} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 1} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 0} \right)}}} \right)\\
 \\
 + p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 1,E_l^m = 1} \right)\\
 \\
 \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 1,E_l^m = 1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 0} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 1} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 1} \right)}}} \right)\\
 \\
 + p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 0} \right)\\
 \\
 \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 0} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 1} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 0} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 0} \right)}}} \right)\\
 \\
 + p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 1} \right)\\
 \\
 \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 1} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 0} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 1} \right)}}} \right)\\
 \\
 + p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 1,E_l^m = 0} \right)\\
 \\
 \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 1,E_l^m = 0} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 1} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 1} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 0} \right)}}} \right)\\
 \\
 + p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 1,E_l^m = 1} \right)\\
 \\
 \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 1,E_l^m = 1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 1} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 1} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 1} \right)}}} \right)\\
 \\
 + p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 0} \right)\\
 \\
 \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 0} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 0} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 0} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 0} \right)}}} \right)\\
 \\
 + p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 1} \right)\\
 \\
 \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 0} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 0} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 1} \right)}}} \right)\\
 \\
 \\
 + p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 1,E_l^m = 1} \right)\\
 \\
 \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 1,E_l^m = 1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 0} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 1} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 1} \right)}}} \right)\\
 %\\
 + p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 0} \right)\\
 \\
 \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 0} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 1} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 0} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 0} \right)}}} \right)\\
 \\
 + p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 1} \right)\\
 \\
 \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 1} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 0} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 1} \right)}}} \right)\\
 \\
 + p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 1,E_l^m = 0} \right)\\
 \\
 \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 1,E_l^m = 0} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 1} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 1} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 0} \right)}}} \right)\\
 \\
 + p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 1,E_l^m = 1} \right)\\
 \\
 \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 1,E_l^m = 1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 1} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 1} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 1} \right)}}} \right)
\end{array}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Have you considered using an `align*` environment instead of nested `equation`/`array` environment? This setup would allow page and column breaks if `\allowdisplaybreaks` is in force.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `array` and any multi line math environment inside `equation` environment can not be split over pages or columns.
- newer use sequence `\\ \\`
- who will read so long equation?

you can write your equation as follows:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \MoveEqLeft
MI\left( {{E_i},{E^t},E_k^n,E_l^m} \right) = \\
& p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 0} \right)\\
& \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 0} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 0} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 0} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 0} \right)}}} \right)\\
& + p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 1} \right)\\
& \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 0} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 0} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 1} \right)}}} \right)\\
& + p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 1,E_l^m = 0} \right)\\
& \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 1,E_l^m = 0} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 0} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 1} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 0} \right)}}} \right)\\
& + p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 1,E_l^m = 1} \right)\\
& \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 1,E_l^m = 1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 0} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 1} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 1} \right)}}} \right)\\
& + p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 0} \right)\\
& \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 0} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 1} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 0} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 0} \right)}}} \right)\\
& + p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 1} \right)\\
& \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 1} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 0} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 1} \right)}}} \right)\\
& + p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 1,E_l^m = 0} \right)\\
& \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 1,E_l^m = 0} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 1} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 1} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 0} \right)}}} \right)\\
& + p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 1,E_l^m = 1} \right)\\
& \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 1,E_l^m = 1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 1} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 1} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 1} \right)}}} \right)\\
& + p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 0} \right)\\
& \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 0} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 0} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 0} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 0} \right)}}} \right)\\
& + p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 1} \right)\\
& \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 0} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 0} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 1} \right)}}} \right)\\
& + p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 1,E_l^m = 1} \right)\\
& \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 1,E_l^m = 1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 0} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 1} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 1} \right)}}} \right)\\
& + p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 0} \right)\\
& \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 0} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 1} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 0} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 0} \right)}}} \right)\\
& + p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 1} \right)\\
& \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 1} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 0} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 1} \right)}}} \right)\\
& + p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 1,E_l^m = 0} \right)\\
& \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 1,E_l^m = 0} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 1} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 1} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 0} \right)}}} \right)\\
& + p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 1,E_l^m = 1} \right)\\
& \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j^t = 1,E_k^n = 1,E_l^m = 1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 1} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 1} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 1} \right)}}} \right)
\end{align*} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how to add a label to this equation